# What is the relation between the following two optical isomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

[image: the two isomers]

I think they should be diastereomers, but the answer to this question is enantiomers, if it is enantiomers then how?

Comment: They are mirror images. Look at the $(S,R)$ configuration of each chiral center.

Comment: Rotate one of them by 180-degrees. Compare.

Answer (score 1):

you can check this out it is not exactly the same but Cl is replaced by OH

[image: you can check this out it is not exactly the same but Cl is replaced by OH]